# Standalone component on a e-commerce site using vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I got this assignment and since I am new with Vue.js, I could use some help. Does anyone know how to do this:
Create a standalone Vue.js component named QuantityInput for the purpose of entering product quantity in various scenarios on an eCommerce website. The component should accept the following properties:

```
initial/selected/entered value: Number (non-negative integer)
select-min: minimum value for select list, Number (non-negative integer)
select-max: maximum value for select list, Number (non-negative integer)
```

The component should always display select list unless user explicitly chooses to enter the value (by selecting 10+ which is the last option), when it displays text input. In the event of value change input event should be emitted.

Here is the link that might help: https://bloomgroove.com/
Put something in a cart and click on it. There you should see that component in action.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I will post a code bellow. I am stuck at this point. I need to hide select tag when user clicks on 10+, and show input and button and when I click on it, span should show value I entered.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">


    <list-app></list-app>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script>

    Vue.component('list-app', {
        template: `
        <div>
        <h2>Quantity input</h2>
            <select v-model="selected" >
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10+</option>
            </select>
            <div>
              <input type="number" style="width:50px" />
              <button v-on:click="update">Update</button>
            </div>
            <span>Cart: ({{ selected }}) </span>
        </div>
        `,
        data() {
             return { 
                numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                cart: 0,
                selected: 0
           }
        },
        methods: {
            update(value) {
                this.selected = value
            }
        }
    });

    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',

    });

</script>
```